# Media Query for Android Devices

Tags: css, media-queries

I have my site optimized for OS and iOS, but testing it for Android through browserstack.com has left me puzzled about targeting Android devices in my media queries.

Here is my query that works for iOS devices:

```
#using em based query after reading this article: http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/
@media only screen and (device-width: 20em)
```

I have tried a variety of different queries (including px based queries), but just want one that will work for all / most handheld android devices. Have you had any luck with this? Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: What browser are you testing this in?

Comment: Using Firefox and browserstack.com. Thanks for any ideas @Asad

Comment: Are you saying that you are having difficulty targeting specific styles to your android device, or that media queries are not showing up at __all__ on android devices?

Comment: If you're using Firefox, that entire rule is going to be discarded, since `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` is invalid for Firefox

Comment: Just saying that the media query is not being applied to android devices @NickTomlin. Using (device-width:20em) is not targeting the android devices

Comment: The media queries are chained @Asad, meaning that it should target devices that have either (device-width:20em) or (device-width:20em) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2). Using only (device-width:20em) does not work, either.

Comment: `width:20em` does not work either, unfortunately..

Comment: The device is unlikely to have a width of exactly 20 em. Did you mean to use min or max?

Answer (score 0):

Media queries can't be used to find device type, you should use user agent sniffing for this.
There is a good resource for media queries on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) though.

Answer (score 0):

Please have look into the demo at http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

It seems like `device-width: 20em` would cause some problems. So have look here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `1em = 16px` I would use the below media query

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 20em) and (max-device-width: 30em)
```

That would look for any `screen` device whose width is between `320px` and `480px`, which is a fairly good standard for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to target Android using media queries, I think you can fake it by querying dpi.

```
@media screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { … }
```