# Place buttons (or divs) one below the other if they can't fit in screen resolution

Tags: html, wordpress, css, wordpress-theming

I am making website (using wordpress) for desktop and mobile users. I placed 4 "buttons" next to each other, but problem is when user with small screen resolution (i.e. user that connect on website using mobile phone) that buttons are resized and it looks ugly. Is there any way to place these button one bellow the other if they can't fit on screen ? Here is CSS that I am using for there 4 buttons:

```
#downloadButton1{
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background:url('download-button1.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  display:block;
  width: 30%;
  height:65px;
}
#downloadButton2{
margin-left:35%;
margin-top:-65px;
 background:url('download-button2.png') no-repeat;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-position: center center;
  display:block;
  width: 20%;
  height:65px;
}
#downloadButton3{
margin-left:58.5%;
margin-top:-65px;
 background:url('download-button3.png') no-repeat;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-position: center center;
  display:block;
  width: 20%;
  height:65px;
}
#downloadButton4{
margin-left:81%;
margin-top:-65px;
 background:url('download-button4or.png') no-repeat;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-position: center center;
  display:block;
  width: 20%;
  height:65px;

}
```

Comment: you may want to refer to the question (link below) and my answer with the link provided:::: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579304/media-query-for-android-devices/15579548#15579548

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the button width is set using percent, they will always shrink to fit within their container. If you remove the width declarations and use left/right padding instead, buttons that don't fit in the container will drop to the next line.

The margin-left declarations also appear to be unnecessary. Not quite sure why you've included those; if removing the margin/width declarations doesn't work, it would be helpful to view your HTML to see the buttons in context.